# How to open angular2-multiselect-dropdown on clicking external button

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I was trying to access angular2-multiselect-dropdown vesrion 4.6.3 .

Here, I wanted to open the dropdown on external button click.

```
<angular2-multiselect 
  [data]="dropdownList" 
  [(ngModel)]="selectedItems"
  [settings]="dropdownSettings" 
  #dropdownRef>
</angular2-multiselect>
        
<button (click)="openDropdown" >
  Click Here to Open Dropdown
</button>
    
@ViewChild('dropdownRef',{static:false}) dropdownRef: AngularMultiSelect;
            
openDropdown(){
  // Open Dropdown Method not working
  this.dropdownRef.openDropdown();
 }
```

Reproduce link : https://stackblitz.com/edit/r7-angular2-multislect-8as6pk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was only able to use CSS properties to control the display.

```
  onItemSelect(item: any) {
    console.log(item);
    console.log(this.dropdownList);

    this.renderer.removeStyle(this.getElementDropdown(), 'display')
  }

  openDropdown(){
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.getElementDropdown(), 'display', 'block');
  }

  private getElementDropdown(): HTMLElement{
    return document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-list")[0] as HTMLElement;
  }
```

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/r7-angular2-multislect-8as6pk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

You can test it here.

Comment: You're right! I will update my answer using CSS, I have not found a better solution.

Comment: By using CSS, its working, but I have multiple angular library components on same page, so by using CSS all dropdown get to open.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/r7-angular2-multislect-8as6pk?file=src/app/app.component.html